# Chrome Native Messaging API chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

**I am looking to manipulate the content page that's currently on the tab in Chrome and if this below can not do that then I need to find the way in order to do that!**

Hey all I am trying to get this new chrome extension working with my C# program to pass messages back and forth. I've seen a lot of demos of code on stackoverflow and that's mainly what I've been going by but it seems that all the examples are not working on my end.

The issue I am having is I am getting the error of:

```
Connecting to native messaging host com.google.chrome.example.echo
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function
```

[image]

Whenever I try to "connect" to the port.

Not sure what I am doing wrong since I have followed other tetorials on here and they all seem to state it works....

**The JS main.js:**

```
var port = null;
var getKeys = function (obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
}
function appendMessage(text) {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>";
}
function updateUiState() {
    if (port) {
        document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function sendNativeMessage() {
    message = { "text": document.getElementById('input-text').value };
    port.postMessage(message);
    appendMessage("Sent message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
}
function onNativeMessage(message) {
    appendMessage("Received message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
}
function onDisconnected() {
    appendMessage("Failed to connect: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    port = null;
    updateUiState();
}
function connect() {
    var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
    appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")
    console.log("Connecting to native messaging host " + hostName);
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
    updateUiState();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('connect-button').addEventListener(
        'click', connect);
    document.getElementById('send-message-button').addEventListener(
        'click', sendNativeMessage);
    updateUiState();
});
```

**The manifest.json:**

```
{
  // Extension ID: knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

The Registry:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json" /f
```

**C# code:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace talkWithChromeCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JObject data;
            while ((data = Read()) != null)
            {
                var processed = ProcessMessage(data);
                Write(processed);
                if (processed == "exit")
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string ProcessMessage(JObject data)
        {
            var message = data["message"].Value<string>();
            switch (message)
            {
                case "test":
                    return "testing!";
                case "exit":
                    return "exit";
                default:
                    return "echo: " + message;
            }
        }

        public static JObject Read()
        {
            var stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
            var length = 0;

            var lengthBytes = new byte[4];
            stdin.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);
            length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);

            var buffer = new char[length];
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stdin))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            return (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(new string(buffer))["data"];
        }

        public static void Write(JToken data)
        {
            var json = new JObject();
            json["data"] = data;

            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString(Formatting.None));

            var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 0) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 8) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 16) & 0xFF));
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 24) & 0xFF));
            stdout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stdout.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "native-messaging-example-host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

**HTML main.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='connect-button'>Connect</button>
    <input id='input-text' type='text' />
    <button id='send-message-button'>Send</button>
    <div id='response'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My directory structure in Visual Studio:

```
C:\Users\t||||||\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\talkWithChromeCSharp\talkWithChromeCSharp
   -APP
     |-icon-128.png
     |-main.html
     |-main.js
     |-manifest.json
   -bin
     |-Debug
        |-Newtonsoft.Json.dll
        |-talkWithChromeCSharp.exe
        |-etc etc...
     |-Release
   -obj
   -Properties
   -regs
     |-com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json
     |-install_host.bat
     |-etc etc...
```

After starting VS debug I install the plugin and load up the main.html file on the chrome browser and click the "connect" button. That's when I get that error.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

That is the correct ID for it. I kept it that way since i'm guessing the "KEY" is what determines the ID.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]" -> that is a copy paste from the example page .. what is your extension  id? try using the right one

Comment: @DanielBatkilin thats incorrect. Its the correct ID for that Key.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have changed the tag. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Please add the output of console.log("" + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(chrome.runtime));
, while running through your main.html page

Comment: @DanielBatkilin **PlatformOs,PlatformArch,PlatformNaclArch,RequestUpdateCheckStatus,OnInstalledReason,OnRestartRequiredReason,connect,sendMessage**

Comment: Try running the command from your background page .. seems you really don't have the permission set for this ( I'm not sure why ) -> sometimes google does massive changes to the API between chrome versions without prior notice

Comment: @StealthRT: http://i.imgur.com/LMEYNoZ.png -  i used your C# code, but when i launch it it crash. see screenshot can you explain why crashing? Visual studio 2013, Windows 8.1, Browser Google chrome version 46, 47, 48, 50..

Comment: This code works for sending the Native application text to Chrome app: https://gist.github.com/hubplace/9465a081c786fa0f685e

Answer (score 10):

Too many confusions and not well explained which really worked for me.
Therefore, here i am trying to make a ``idiot proof` doc. (Please improve this version)

**Goal:** Windows OS, Google chrome till version 50 tested, communicate to Native application

---

**Step 1:**

---

Download:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app.zip

**Step 2:**

---

Load the downloaded app to Google chrome

[image]

**Step 3:**

---

**a)** add the registry key

`REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\\run-my-exe\\manifest.json" /f`

[image]

**b)** To make a custom chrome executer, copy the following into C:\run-my-exe\run-chrome.bat:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable--native-messaging --native-messaging-hosts="com.google.chrome.example.echo=C:\\run-my-exe\\manifest.json"`

**Step 4: Host**

---

**a)** put following to C:\run-my-exe\manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "native-messaging-example-host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

**b)** put following to C:\run-my-exe\native-messaging-example-host.bat

```
@echo off
cd %windir%\system32
start calc.exe
```

**Step 5: How do i now run it?**

---

**a)** open chrome with this script: `C:\\run-my-exe\\run-chrome.bat`

**b)** in the chrome go to `chrome://apps`

**c)** launch

via the icon

[image]

not as below:

[image]

**Final Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these instructions.  At first it wasn't working for me, but it is now.  I had previously tried the app and had the same registry key in current user as well as local machine.  The current user key was invalid.  After deleting and re-running I have the calc popping up.  One question, is there any way to call the exe with a parameter?

Comment: @YumYumYum, **But wait**, isn't Google going to remove Chrome Apps from Chrome by 2018? See https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html so in other words, this is not going to work any more in the future? I've submitted a request at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSenHdpA8_eqKiVOrWDjWe_KTfJmoSBEqFIh6SMwQ-NRDJnx1Q/viewform to request it for inclusion  in the future, but we need more people telling the Chrome team that native messaging is Important.

Comment: NO - lets shutdown the Chrome apps from Google Chrome, they are scaring the planet, as community we should rule Google chrome not Google chrome should rule us.

Comment: @YumYumYum, We need people to spam this form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSenHdpA8_eqKiVOrWDjWe_KTfJmoSBEqFIh6SMwQ-NRDJnx1Q/viewform and tell them to include the `connectNative` functions, otherwise the Chrome team would go ahead and ignore us again.

Comment: Btw step 3b is not needed. I've tried without `--enable--native-messaging` and without `--native-messaging-hosts` and it works. The only thing that is required is the registry installation.

Comment: @YumYumYum, Dam, it seems like this answer no longer works anymore. I get `ERROR:native_process_launcher.cc(147) Failed to load manifest for native messaging host com.google.chrome.example.echo: Invalid value for name.`. For your environment does the steps outlined in this answer still work?

Comment: Which version you used? maybe Google Chrome removed it. Can you try Chromium version 46 or Chromium older?

Comment: Best example there is. Step 2 could be more detailed, i.e. type chrome://extensions in the url to get to the extensions tab, then press the Load Unpacked Extensions button, then select the app folder in your solution (the app folder includes the main.js, main.html and manifest.json).

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to open main.html directly, but rather from Chrome's App Launcher at chrome://apps/

Comment: YES - launching from `chrome://apps/` it worked. But how can i launch it like `http://localhost` or `https://myserver.com/sameapp` and connect same way?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I think you add the app to the Chrome Web Store and people install it locally.

Comment: See that is the problem, it was never well documented how to use it from http:// or https:// . i need to use it not using chrome://apps concept.

Answer (score 0):

Beware copy-paste !

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app/manifest.json

I would assume that's where you got your manifest.
Replace the "key" with the proper one

and in "allowed_origins" use your actual extension id instead of the one from the example

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key

There may be more errors there, but those are just the ones I catch in a first look.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C# project which generate an `exe` file as its output, the file of `native-messaging-example-host.bat` should not be like original example that was sth like this:

```
python "%~dp0/native-messaging-example-host" %*
```

Instead, the batch file should change as follows:

```
@echo off
Pushd C:\Users\h.aghajani\Desktop\host  /*Path directory of your exe*/
start native-messaging-example-host.exe /*Name of the execution file*/
```